# Use Excel INDEX to create a series of text labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using [this](https://templates.office.com/en-us/Julian-calendar-any-year-TM03934539) Excel template to create a calendar. I am trying to add additional text next to the Julian Day. The text comes from a range with values "D", "P", "L".

Starting on Monday, the value should be "D", Tuesday is "DP", Wednesday is "DPL", Thursday is "DP", and Friday is "L". Weekends have no additional text.

The next week follows the same pattern but begins with "P".

The result is something like this:

```
Week | M | T | W | T | F |
--------------------------
  1  | D |PL |DPL|DP | L |
--------------------------
  2  | P |LD |PLD|PL | D |
--------------------------
  3  | L |DP |LDP|LD | P |
```

And it just keeps going...

Answer (score 0):

1. At the start of each month, enter in the proper "P,D,L" value
2. A formula for Tuesday would look like (assuming Monday is `A1`

   =if(A1="D","PL",if(A1="P","LD",if(A1="L","DP")))
3. For Wed. - Fri, create a similar formula based on the previous days value (i.e. if Mon was `A1` and Tue was `B1` then writing Wed formula in `C1` you would write `=if(C1...`)
4. After writing formulas for Tues - Fri for the first week, copy and paste to the second week and beyond.
5. For the second, third, etc. Monday of each month, write the following formula (assuming the first Mon is `A1` and the second Mon is located in `A2`

   =if(A1="D","P",if(A1="P","L",if(A1="L","P")))
6. While you can copy the same Tue - Fri formulas across all weeks for the year, the Mon formula can be copied except you need to manually specify the value on the first Mon of each month.

---

**ADDENDUM 201905270228**

Here is the general approach to use index.

1. Create a new table (to server as a reference array for INDEX to call upon) with days of the week along the top x-axis in numerical for (e.g. Mon=1, Tue=2, etc.) and along the y-axis enter week numbers. Then populate this table with your D,P,L outcomes for each week-day combination.
2. As for the formulas in each day of the calendar, you need a formula similar to the following template:

   `=index([array created in step 1],[embedded formula that extracts the week number from entry and Sunday column e.g. =weeknum(..._],[embedded formula that converts day of week to corresponding day number in array, e.g. =weekday(...)])`

If this solves your problem, please mark as your answer.

Comment: But Brian, the title says: "Use Excel **INDEX** to ...". Your answer doesn't address that requirement.

Comment: Fair enough. It is more complicated solution but you can feel free to create that solution, Tom, if you want. I would rework the more complicated solution myself if the original poster indicated he had a specific reason for using INDEX if he needed it other than for homework help. But, may posters get stuck on the idea that a specific function is the solution but they simply can't figure out how without considering there are other solutions that are easier to accomplish. I provided a solution that accomplished the outcomes he desired without spending more time I didn't have on complex solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Brian. This is certainly a partial solution. The problem is this pattern of 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 continues for 45 combinations before it repeats, and I need it to repeat hundreds of times. Using an IF formula is equivalent to hard-coding the repeating pattern. With INDEX, you can select the items needed in the next combination, but how would you actually loop through the INDEX range?

Comment: I think I may be missing what the pattern is; what is the 4th row in your example? (I was inferring the 4th row to be `  4  | D |PL |DPL|DP | L |`)

Comment: The fourth row would be "PL, DPL, DP, L, P". I forgot to mention that at the end of three iterations of 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, the first number goes to the end of the line and the pattern becomes 2, 3, 2, 1, 1. After another three iterations, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2.